# Expressing a Quadratic in $a(x + b)^2 + c$ form

Tags: quadratics, factoring

I have question as follows: Express $2x^2 - 6x + 7$ in the form $a(x + b)^2 + c$.

My approach is to complete the square so I did this:

$(2x^2 + 6/2)^2 - (6/2)^2 + 7 = 0$

$(2x^2 - 3)^2 - 9 + 7 = 0$

$(2x^2 - 3)^2 - 2 = 0$

I got a bit lost here and not sure how to proceed forward.

Comment: You don't seem to have the right idea in completing the square (there's no reason why you must have an expression with $x^2$ being squared again, for instance). You might want to review your text or lecture notes before you look at the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it with
$$2\left(x^2-3x+\frac{7}{2}\right)=2\left(x^2-2\cdot \frac{3}{2}x+\frac{9}{4}-\frac{9}{4}+\frac{7}{2}\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
$$2x^2 - 6x + 7=ax^2+2abx+ab^2+c$$
$$a=2$$
$$-6=2ab$$
$$7=ab^2+c$$

Answer (score 0):

$2x^2-6x+7 = 2(x^2-3x)+7=2(x^2-3x+(\frac 32)^2) -2(\frac 32)^2+7 =2(x-\frac 32)^2+\frac 52$

Answer (score 0):

Let's investigate completing the square for the general case:

$$ax^2+bx+c$$

Factor out the $a$ to obtain

$$a\left(x^2+\frac{b}{a}x+\frac{c}{a}\right)\tag{*}$$

Let's complete the square on the bracketed term. We Need to write this as $(x+B)^2$, so start with

$$\left(x+\frac{b}{a}\right)^2=x^2+2\frac{b}{a}x+\frac{b^2}{a^2}.$$

But wait ! We've got 2 lots of $b/a$ when we expand it, so what we really should use instead is

$$\left(x+\frac{b}{2a}\right)^2=x^2+\frac{b}{a}x+\frac{b^2}{4a^2}.$$

Now that's better, but this square introduces the unwanted term $b^2/(4a^2)$, so we will need to remove that,

$$\left(x+\frac{b}{2a}\right)^2-\frac{b^2}{4a^2}=x^2+\frac{b}{a}x.$$
That's exactly what we want, except that we need a $c/a$ term, so let's add that back in,

$$\left(x+\frac{b}{2a}\right)^2-\frac{b^2}{4a^2}+\frac{c}{a}=x^2+\frac{b}{a}x+\frac{c}{a}.$$

This is precisely what is required, so just sub this back into (*) and we get

$$a\left(\left(x+\frac{b}{2a}\right)^2-\frac{b^2}{4a^2}+\frac{c}{a}\right).$$

Expanding, we have

$$a\left(x+\frac{b}{2a}\right)^2+c-\frac{b^2}{4a}\equiv A(x+B)^2+C,$$

where $A=a$, $$B=\frac{b}{2a},$$ and $$C=c-\frac{b^2}{4a}.$$

Answer (score 0):

To proceed, assume $y=2x^2-3$ then we get $y^2-2=0$ as follows:
$$
assume:\quad y = 2x^2-3 \\
y^2-2=0 \\
y=\pm\sqrt{2} \\
(1)\qquad y=\sqrt{2} \\
2x^2-3=\sqrt{2} \\
x=\pm\sqrt{\frac{3+\sqrt{2}}{2}} \\
(2) \qquad y=\sqrt{-2}=\sqrt{2}i \\
2x^2-3=\sqrt{2}i \\
x=\pm\sqrt{\frac{3+\sqrt{2}i}{2}}
$$